# find the slope and intercepts of the line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

a) $3x+2y=6$

b) $5y-3x=4$

Am i correct in my letter a) 
$3x+(-3x)+2y=-3x+6$

$2y=-3x+6$

multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot2y=\frac{1}{2}(-3x+6)$

answer is $y=\frac{-3}{2x+3}$ ?
my solution is like this

5y-3x=4
= 5y-3x+4 = 0
then i don't know the next step please help me

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: And yes: apparently you're correct (if I understand correctly what you wrote), yet that doesn't answer your question's title.

Comment: The same method applies to b). You need to solve for $y$.

Comment: $y=\frac{-3}{2x+3}$ is not right,$x$ is not supposed to end up in the denominator,poor $x$ ...

Comment: The next step is to review the Distributive Property. I believe that this item was discussed in grade 4.

Answer (score 2):

I will demonstrate how to do the first problem.  The same methods can be applied to the second problem, which I will leave to you.

An $x$-intercept is a point, if it exists, where the line intersects the $x$-axis.  Each point on the $x$-axis has $y$-coordinate $0$.  Thus, to find the $x$-intercept, set $y = 0$ and solve for $x$.

\begin{align*}
3x + 2y & = 6\\
3x + 2(0) & = 6\\
3x + 0 & = 6\\
3x & = 6\\
x & = 2
\end{align*}

A $y$-intercept is a point, if it exists, where the line intersects the $y$-axis.  Each point on the $y$-axis has $x$-coordinate $0$.  Thus, to find the $y$-intercept, set $x = 0$ and solve for $y$.

\begin{align*}
3x + 2y & = 6\\
3(0) + 2y & = 6\\
0 + 2y & = 6\\
2y & = 6\\
y & = 3
\end{align*}

Thus, the line $3x + 2y = 6$ passes through the points $(2, 0)$ and $(0, 3)$.  The slope of a line that passes through the points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is

$$m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$

Hence, the slope of the line $3x + 2y = 6$ is

$$m = \frac{0 - 3}{2 - 0} = -\frac{3}{2}$$

If you transform the equation from standard form to slope-intercept form, you obtain

\begin{align*}
3x + 2y & = 6\\
2y & = -3x + 6 && \text{subtract $3x$ from each side of the equation}\\
y & = -\frac{3}{2}x + 3 && \text{divide each side of the equation by $2$}
\end{align*}

Since the equation has the form $y = mx + b$, where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept, we see that the slope is $-3/2$ and the $y$-intercept is $3$, which agrees with the answers we obtained above.  However, you would still have to set $y = 0$ to solve for the $x$-intercept.